# Javascript onchange option value

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to display the unit when I click on the select tag.  I used the Switch statement but it didn't do anything.

HTML:

```
<select class="unit_from">
    <option value = "Kilogram">Kilogram</option>
</select>

<select id="unit_to" onchange="convert()">
 <option value = "Metric_ton">Metric ton</option>
 <option value = "Kilogram">Kilogram</option>
 <option value = "Gram">Gram</option>
 <option value = "Milligram">Miligram</option>
 <option value = "Mcg">Mcg</option>
 <option value = "Long_ton">Long ton</option>
 <option value = "Stone">Stone</option>
 <option value = "Pound">Pound</option>
 <option value = "Ounce">Ounce</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="text_input">
 <input id="txtValue" type="text" />
 <p id="print_ans"></p>
```

When the option value is selected, the unit is to be displayed in the paragraph id=print_ans.

Javascript:

```
<script>
function convert()
    {
        var kilo = document.getElementById("txtValue").value;  
        var get_unit = convert_unit();
    }

        function convert_unit()
        {
            var x;
            var y = document.getElementById("unit_to").value;  
            switch(y)
            {
                case Metric_ton:
                    x = kilo * 0.001;
                    break;
                case Kilogram:
                    x =  kilo * 1;
                    break;
                case Gram:
                    x = kilo * 1000;
                    break;
                case Milligram:
                    x = kilo *0.000001;
                    break;
                case Mcg:
                    x = kilo * 0.000000001;
                    break;
                case Long_ton:
                    x = kilo * 0.000984207;
                    break;
                case Stone:
                    x = kilo * 0.00110231;
                    break;
                case Pound:
                    x = kilo * 0.157473;
                    break;
                case Ounce:
                    x= kilo * 2.20462;
                    break;
            }
            document.getElementById("print_ans").innerHTML = x;
        }
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Gtcd/4/

Comment: Use jQuery! You wont regret it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several errors:

in your `switch` statement you use things like `case Metric_ton:` but `Metric_ton` is supposed to be a string, not a variable, so it should be written `case 'Metric_ton':`

also, `kilo` is not assigned a value in the function `convert_unit`, it is outside of the scope of that function, so you need something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Gtcd/9/

where `kilo` is assigned a value within `convert_unit`. Infact I renamed `convert_unit` to `convert` and deleted the original `convert` function, as it seemed unnecessary.